# Remove semicolon and separating outputs from a list of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, permutation

I have this random combination generator, which finding every possible combination of the given arrays by as many digit as I want:

```
var Util = function() {
};

Util.getCombinations = function(array, size, start, initialStuff, output) {
    if (initialStuff.length >= size) {
        output.push(initialStuff);
    } else {
        var i;

        for (i = start; i < array.length; ++i) {  
      Util.getCombinations(array, size, i + 1, initialStuff.concat(array[i]), output);
        }
    }
}

Util.getAllPossibleCombinations = function(array, size, output) {
    Util.getCombinations(array, size, 0, [], output);
}

var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

for (var i=1; i<=array; ++i) {
  array[i - 1] = i;
}

var output = [];

Util.getAllPossibleCombinations(array, 2, output);
console.log(output);
document.write(output);
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n1sqbrw2/

I want the output to look like this:

`document.write(var + ', ');`

`ab, ac, ad, ae, af, ...`

What I need to edit in this script to beautify the output?

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to change each individual array within `output` to a string, then use **[`join(', ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** to beautify:

```
output.map(function(val) {
  return val.join('');    //join the array to make a string
}).join(', ');            //join the strings to beautify
```

```js
var Util = function() {};

Util.getCombinations = function(array, size, start, initialStuff, output) {
  if (initialStuff.length >= size) {
    output.push(initialStuff);
  } else {
    var i;

    for (i = start; i < array.length; ++i) {
      Util.getCombinations(array, size, i + 1, initialStuff.concat(array[i]), output);
    }
  }
}

Util.getAllPossibleCombinations = function(array, size, output) {
  Util.getCombinations(array, size, 0, [], output);
}

var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

for (var i = 1; i <= array; ++i) {
  array[i - 1] = i;
}

var output = [];

Util.getAllPossibleCombinations(array, 2, output);

console.log(output.map(function(val) {
  return val.join('');
}).join(', '));
```

Comment: Thank You! It's perfect!